# The problem of reading data from the store at the first start

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist

I have a weather application that, when launched through a request, determines the city by IP and saves it to the store, and immediately after that the weather for this city should be displayed

here is my code

```
 const { isPending, days, error, currentDayWeather } =
    useTypedSelector((state) => state.weather)
  const weatherCity = useTypedSelector(
    (state) => state.weather.weather?.city,
  )
  const userCity = useTypedSelector(
    (state: any) => state.location?.location?.city?.name_en,
  )
  const { service } = useTypedSelector(
    (state) => state.service,
  )

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getGeolocation())
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getWeather(userCity))
  }, [userCity])

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelected(0)
  }, [weatherCity])

  if (isPending || !weatherCity) return <Loading />
  if (!days || error) return <ErrorLoader />

  return (
    <WeatherWrapper>
      <WeatherMain
        params={weatherCity}
        currentWeather={currentDayWeather}
      />
      <WeatherListCard>
        {days.map((item: ResultDaysType, index: number) => (
          <WeatherItem
            key={uuidv4()}
            day={index}
            weatherData={item}
            active={selected === index}
            onChangeSelected={setSelected}
          />
        ))}
      </WeatherListCard>
      {service === SERVICES[1] && <ChartWeather />}
    </WeatherWrapper>
  )
}
```

when I check with react dev tools, the status is filled with correct data, but when I first run the error field is true
[image]

and because of this, the application does not start, and when the page is reloaded, everything is fine

maybe it has something to do with using redux-persist?

**store.ts**

```
...
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const configureStore = () =>
  createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
  )

const store = configureStore()
const persistor = persistStore(store)

export { store, persistor }
```

**Reducers**

```
export const locationReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: { location: any, type: string },
): initialStateType => {
  const { location, type } = action

  switch (type) {
    case TYPES.GET_LOCATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        location
      }
    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

```
export const weatherReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: any,
): initialStateType => {
  const {
    weather, days, isPending, error, type,
} = action

  switch (type) {
    case TYPES.SET_WEATHER:
      return {
        ...state,
        weather,
        days
      }
    case TYPES.SET_WEATHER_HOURLY:
      return {
        ...state,
        weatherHourly: weather,
      }
    case TYPES.SET_PENDING:
      return {
        ...state,
        isPending
      }
    case TYPES.SET_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error
      }
    case TYPES.CHANGE_DAY:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentDayWeather: state?.days![action.payload] ?? false,
        weatherOnHours: {
          temp: state?.days![action.payload].weather.map((temp) => Math.round(+temp.main.temp)) ?? false,
          date: state?.days![action.payload].weather.map((temp) => temp.dt_txt) ?? false,
        },
      }
    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

**thunk**

```
export const getWeather = (city: string): ThunkType<ActionsTypes<typeof actions>> => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(actions.setPending(true))
    dispatch(actions.setError(false))

    const weather = await weatherApi.getWeather(city)

    dispatch(actions.setWeather(weather))
    dispatch(actions.changeDay(0))
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    dispatch(actions.setError(true))
  } finally {
    dispatch(actions.setPending(false))
  }
}
```

Comment: You should show your store config

Comment: I guess that `initialState` has `error` set to `true` or you thunk sets it to `true`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Your advice helped to avoid reloading the page for display, but I have implemented it so that as the city was determined, it is entered in the search input, but this does not happen at the first render, only at the next